# How do I turn off intellisense for javascript?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

While editing javascript content VisualStudio is starting to bug me with how it keeps inserting highlighted suggestions. For example it keeps inserting `valueOf(` if I type `val(`. This is really annoying.

I want to invoke intellisense manually just like I can with C#, is there any way of turning off the auto-complete suggestion or at least preventing it from selecting an entry for me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Visual Studio Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript
In corresponding panel as **Statement completion**
Uncheck **Autolist members & Parameter Information**

I think that should do the trick

Comment: Myra, you little legend. You also helped me find an alternative: "Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript", "Miscellaneous" tab, tick "Only use Tab or Enter to commit".

Comment: The option "Only use Tab or Enter to commit" is already checked in my options.  Nevertheless, when I type the open parenthesis in "val(" Visual Studio 2010 always replaces it with "valueOf(".  This is infuriating.  I'd love to know how to prevent this without fully disabling javascript intellisense.

Comment: Still painfully slows down VS every time though, so I don't see the benefit in even disabling it. Geez, Microsoft...

Comment: I have followed the instructions above (I use VS 2010) however I still see the following in my output window: 

Javascript Intellisense Message: D:\XXXX\jquery-1.7.2.min.js(4:15602) : Function expected

What gives? (And it's not just for the jquery file, for other files too)

Answer (score 4):

I realize resharper isn't mentioned in the question, however there is an easy solution if you're using it.

Navigate to Resharper -> Options -> Intellisense -> Completing Character. Once there, add ".val(" to the "Do not complete on" text field beside the JavaScript row.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I tried Myra's solution but it didn't solve it completely for me due to ReSharper. Turned out it was the ReSharper intellisense that autocompleted whatever I was writing to the current/top option in the intellisense list, not the VS default intellisense.

I fixed this by turning off ReSharper's JavaScript support completely by going to ReSharper -> Options -> Products & Features -> Uncheck JavaScript and TypeScript.

This might not be a good solution if you depend on any other JavaScript- or TypeScript-related features in ReSharper but I finally got control of the intellisense. Peace, at last...

(Just to be clear, I still have the "Autolist members" and "Parameter Information" options as described in Myra's post above checked/activated, and the "Only use Tab or Enter to commit" option as described in Brett Ryan's comment above also checked/activated)

Answer (score 1):

for me it was also resharper (replacing my .each with .forEach), and what I did is go to 
menu

```
Resharper -> Options    
Environment -> IntelliSense -> Autopopup    
select JavaScript tab    
"After dot" -> select "Display but do not preselect" in the dropdown
```